# execute for loop on remote machine over ssh

Tags: bash, shell, for

i am trying to execute for loop on a remote machine using the below line

```
ssh ubuntu@host -n "RPM=\`ls /var/www/html/tmp/* | for i in "${promotebuilds[@]}" ;  do  grep -E $i /var/www/html/tmp/*; done'\`";
```

This is returning empty output. when i checked on this [link](https://www.shellcheck.net) for the error 
1) Argument mixes string and array. Use * or separate argument.                                                                                      2) Double quote array expansions to avoid re-splitting elements.

Which i did't understood much

Comment: You are using double quotes to quote entire expression and to quote `${promotebuilds[@]}`. Try to remove quotes from this loop exporession because I don't think they are even necessary there

Comment: What's that command supposed to do? Is `${promotebuilds[@]}` supposed to be expanded on the remote or the local side? (If on the remote, it has to be set in your shell's initialization files) Is that `RPM` variable you're setting used anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

> ssh ubuntu@host -n "RPM=`ls /var/www/html/tmp/* | for i in "${promotebuilds[@]}" ;  do  grep -E $i /var/www/html/tmp/*; done'`";

```
ssh ubuntu@host -n 'RPM=$(for i in "${promotebuilds[@]}" ;  do  grep -E $i /var/www/html/tmp/*; done)';
```

as the first pipe was not doing anything and the single quote was unpaired. But you should just scp a sh file and run it.

Comment: No need for `scp`-ing a script, as you can redirect input from local files: `ssh user@host "bash -s" < script.sh`

Comment: Fiximan: that would break dependent scripts, and likely traps for error handling.